# how to autoselect current date in calendar control?

Tags: javascript, jsp, struts

how to autoselect current date in javascript?. 
I am using Calendar .js for displaying calendar,but dont know how to autoselect current date.Please guide me

Edit:
Calender.js

```
var oldLink = null;
// code to change the active stylesheet
function setActiveStyleSheet(link, title) {
  var i, a, main;
  for(i=0; (a = document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
    if(a.getAttribute("rel").indexOf("style") != -1 && a.getAttribute("title")) {
      a.disabled = true;
      if(a.getAttribute("title") == title) a.disabled = false;
    }
  }
  if (oldLink) oldLink.style.fontWeight = 'normal';
  oldLink = link;
  link.style.fontWeight = 'bold';
  return false;
}

// This function gets called when the end-user clicks on some date.
function selected(cal, date) {
  cal.sel.value = date; 
  cal.sel.focus();
  // just update the date in the input field.
//  if ((cal.sel.id).substr(0,3) == "row" || cal.sel.id == "row3")

    cal.callCloseHandler();
}

function closeHandler(cal) {
  cal.hide();                        // hide the calendar
}

function showCalendar(id, format) {
  var el = document.getElementById(id);
  if (calendar != null) {
    // we already have some calendar created
    calendar.hide();      
    // so we hide it first.
  } else {
    // first-time call, create the calendar.
    var cal = new Calendar(false, null, selected, closeHandler);
    // uncomment the following line to hide the week numbers
    // cal.weekNumbers = false;
    calendar = cal;                  // remember it in the global var
    cal.setRange(1900, 2070);        // min/max year allowed.
    cal.create();
  }
  calendar.setDateFormat(format);    // set the specified date format
  calendar.parseDate(el.value);      // try to parse the text in field
  calendar.sel = el;                 // inform it what input field we use
  calendar.showAtElement(el);        // show the calendar below it

  return false;
}

var MINUTE = 60 * 1000;
var HOUR = 60 * MINUTE;
var DAY = 24 * HOUR;
var WEEK = 7 * DAY;


function isDisabled(date) {
  var today = new Date();
  return (Math.abs(date.getTime() - today.getTime()) / DAY) > 10;
}

function flatSelected(cal, date) {
  var el = document.getElementById("preview");
  el.innerHTML = date;
}

function showFlatCalendar() {
  var parent = document.getElementById("display");

  // construct a calendar giving only the "selected" handler.
  var cal = new Calendar(false, null, flatSelected);

  // hide week numbers
  cal.weekNumbers = false;

  // We want some dates to be disabled; see function isDisabled above
  cal.setDisabledHandler(isDisabled);
  cal.setDateFormat("DD, M d");

  cal.create(parent);

  cal.show();
}

function compareDate(date1, date2)
{
    var strErrMsg = "";

    tokens = date1.split("-");
    dd = tokens[0];
    mm = tokens[1];
        mm=mm-1;
    yyyy = tokens[2];
        dt1 = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);

    tokens1 = date2.split("-");
    dd = tokens1[0];
    mm = tokens1[1];
        mm=mm-1;
    yyyy = tokens1[2];
        dt2 = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);

    if(dt1.valueOf() <= dt2.valueOf())

        alert(dt1);
        alert(dt2);

        var difInDays = (parseInt) ((dt2.getTime() - dt1.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
        alert(difInDays);

        if(dt1.valueOf() <= dt2.valueOf())
    {
            return strErrMsg;
        }
    else
        {
            strErrMsg = "Cannot be Greater than ";
            return strErrMsg;
        }

        return strErrMsg;
}

 function nextDateAfterThreeDays(date1)
    {
      tokens = date1.split("-");

      dd = tokens[0];
      mm = parseInt(tokens[1]-1);
      yyyy = tokens[2];

      dt1 = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);

      var time=dt1.getTime();
      time=time;
      dt1.setTime(time);

      var newDD = dt1.getDate()+3;
      var newMM = dt1.getMonth()+1;
      var newYY = dt1.getFullYear();

      if(newDD<10)
          newDD="0"+newDD;

      if(newMM<10)
          newMM="0"+newMM;

      date1=newDD+"-"+newMM+"-"+dt1.getFullYear();
      return date1;
    }


function compareBackDate(date1, date2)
{
        var strErrMsg = "";

        tokens = date1.split("-");

    dd = tokens[0];
    mm = parseInt(tokens[1])-1;
    yyyy = tokens[2];

    dt1 = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);

    tokens = date2.split("-");

    dd = tokens[0];
    mm = parseInt(tokens[1])-1;
    yyyy = tokens[2];

    dt2 = new Date(yyyy,mm,dd);

        var difInDays = (parseInt) ((dt1.getTime() - dt2.getTime())/(1000*60*60*24));
        alert(""+difInDays);

        if(difInDays > 15 )
        {
            strErrMsg = " Should not be earlier six month than ";

        }

        return strErrMsg;
}

function convertDate(date1)
{

    var tokens1;
    var ddd;
    var mmm="";
    var mmm1;
    var yyyyy;
    var strErrMsg="";

    tokens1 = date1.split("-");
    ddd = tokens1[0];
    mmm = tokens1[1];
    yyyyy = tokens1[2];


    if(mmm=="Jan")
    {
      mmm1=01;
    }
    if(mmm=="Feb")
    {
      mmm1=02;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Mar")
    {
      mmm1=03;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Apr")
    {
      mmm1=04;  
    }
    if(mmm=="May")
    {
      mmm1=05;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Jun")
    {
      mmm1=06;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Jul")
    {
      mmm1=07;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Aug")
    {
      mmm1=08;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Sep")
    {
      mmm1=09;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Oct")
    {
      mmm1=10;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Nov")
    {
      mmm1=11;  
    }
    if(mmm=="Dec")
    {
      mmm1=12;  
    }

    strErrMsg=ddd+"-"+mmm1+"-"+yyyyy;

    return strErrMsg;


}

function isComboSelected(objComboName)
{
    var strErrMsg = "";
    var objForm = document.getElementsByTagName("form")[0];
    var objCombo = document.getElementsByName(objComboName)[0];

    if(objCombo.options[0].selected == true)
    {
        strErrMsg = "Please Select Value.";
         return strErrMsg;
    }

    return strErrMsg;
}
```

Edit2:

My code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function submitFun()
{
    var frm=document.forms[0];
    var fromDate=frm.lsReqRecDate.value;
    //var toDate=frm.toDate.value;
    var date1=convertDate(fromDate);
    //var date2=convertDate(toDate);


    var mm;var dd;var yyyy;
    var mm1;var dd1;var yyyy1;
    var d1=date1;

    var txtAppFrmDate=date1;
      if(d1.indexOf("-")!=-1)
      {
        dd=d1.substring(0,d1.indexOf("-"));
        mm=d1.substring(d1.indexOf("-")+1,d1.lastIndexOf("-"));
        yyyy=d1.substring(d1.lastIndexOf("-")+1,d1.length);

      }
      start_Date=new Date(yyyy,mm-1,dd);


      var fDate = txtAppFrmDate.split("-");
     // var tDate = txtAppToDate.split("-");

      var one_day=1000*60*60*24;
      var fdt = new Date((fDate[2]),(fDate[1]-1),(fDate[0]));

    frm.submit();
}
</script>

<html:form action="/exceptionNBReport.do" styleId="frmDatewise">

<TABLE class="ReportFilter">
    <THEAD>
        <TR>
            <TD colspan="2">NB Report Search</TD>
        </TR>
    </THEAD>
</TABLE>
<br><br>
<TABLE class="ReportFilter">

    <TR>
        <TD class="lbl" align="left">Last requirement received date</TD>
        <TD>
            <html:text property="lsReqRecDate" style="width:170;" readonly="readonly"/>
            <input type="reset" value="..." onclick="return showCalendar('lsReqRecDate','dd-MM-y');" name="reset"/>
        </TD>
    </TR>

    <TR>
        <TD colspan="2" align="center">
            <html:button property="search" value="Submit" onclick="submitFun()"/>
        </TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
</html:form>
```

Comment: please be more specific, how many calendar scripts do you think are on the internet?

Answer (score 0):

It would appear from the source code of Calendar that you need to pass the desired date into the Calendar() constructor as the second argument to the constructor. See lines 16 and 588 for details.